# How you solve "preventing common words from Google" issue?

Tags: seo, google, keywords

My topic seems to be solved by stackexchange engine but me (a human) couldn't find a solution here.

As you may understand on subject, I have many repeated words on my site like "comment", "like", "read more" and also some system messages like "mysql_result","error", "php" etc.

I saw that my most valuable words are these on Webmaster's Tools. Some people suggests to load those texts from a js file and restrict access to those files. Or using iframes for those text areas. Both have some negative sides, too.

I think about another solution which is using images instead of repeated texts but it is neither practical nor seems well.

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the occurrences of "mysql_result", "error" or "php" are the result of *PHP errors* on the site, then it should be obvious **you need to fix those errors!** Try and find which pages they appear on (search for example `mysql_result site:example.com` in Google) and fix and problems.

Otherwise, **don't worry about it**. The keywords listed in GWT aren't necessarily the most "valuable", they are just the most common. I have plenty of common words listed on various sites I've developed such as 'pts', 'ago', 'new' and 'its'. In nearly all cases only the top 1 or 2 keywords were directly relevant to the site, with 1-2 more relevant words mixed in lower down.

Definitely do not use iframes or Javascript to load individual words or sentences, unless the site would make complete sense without said iframes or JS. Even then it's probably not worth the hassle and extra page load time.

Comment: Thanks mate, I fixed errors already. It was just sampling based on previous errors :)